# On Bible Verses Defined by the Catholic Church

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, bible, apologetics, galatians

The following link seems to provide some good insight into Bible verses whose meanings have been definitively declared by the Catholic Church.

https://www.catholicfidelity.com/apologetics-topics/bible/bible-verses-defined-by-the-church/

Does anyone know where a more official list may be obtained? Are there any Bible verses that may be added in addition to the ones linked above; in particular, I would very much like to know if the Catholic Church has ever solemnly defined anything on the interpretation of Galatians 1:8-9:

> (8) But though we, or an angel from heaven, preach a gospel to you besides that which we have preached to you, let him be anathema.  (9) As we said before, so now I say again: If any one preach to you a gospel, besides that which you have received, let him be anathema.

The above is taken from the Douay-Rheims.